# How to update all the values of a numpy array using values from another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

*Question edited/updated to add an example

Hi all! I have this `a` np.array. Based on the reference values of it, I want to update array `b`, which is my matrix. The "1st column" of `a` represents a code and the "2nd column" is my reference value. The matrix is populated with codes and I must replace them. See below the example.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([[0, 11], [1, 22], [2, 33]])
b = np.asarray([[0, 14, 12, 2], [1, 1, 7, 0], [0, 0,3,5], [1, 2, 2, 6]])
```

In other words: I want to replace the 0, 1, 2 values in "b" by 11, 22, 33, respectively.

Which is the best way to do that, considering that my real `a` array has +- 50 codes and my real `b`  matrices have a shape of (850,850).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add some example of expected output?

Comment: @RenardKorzeniowski question updated ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this example should show what you're asking for?

Assuming `a` is the matrix as you've listed above, and `b` is the list you want to write to

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([[0, 10], [2, 30], [1, 40]])
b = np.zeros(3)
b[a[:, 0]] = a[:, 1]
```

where the `[:, 0]` is the index to be changed, and `[:, 1]` is what to populate it with

Comment: Thanks! It works when arrays have same dimension, right? In my case the dimension differs so I'm still figuring out how to make it happen. I updated the question with one example. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If codes are not too long integers, You just have to build the correct lookup table :

```
lut = np.arange(b.max()+1)
k,v = a.T
lut[k] = v
```

For :

```
>>> b
[[ 0 14 12  2]
 [ 1  1  7  0]
 [ 0  0  3  5]
 [ 1  2  2  6]]

>>> lut[b]
[[11 14 12 33]
 [22 22  7 11]
 [11 11  3  5]
 [22 33 33  6]]
```

undefined codes are mapped to themselves,`code=value`.

Comment: Great! It is working. You've said that the approach can be used for codes that are not too long integers. If they are, why is not a good idea? Is it because processing time  or sth? In my case, the code range is 1-10000 but the values have around 12-16 digits

Comment: No 10000 << 850², so  lut will be little in regard to your data.

Comment: One more question! My real data has is populated with a negative value that represents "no data" for my analysis . I've tested your solution with one example, but because of the inverted index my output matrix is not what I was expecting. Is there any way to determine that the negative value remains imutable? My example array: b = np.asarray([[0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 10000, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999], [0, 1, 2, 3, -9999]])

Comment: Clearly this -9999 is a bad idea, there is always a day where it will be problematic. work around : `lut = np.arange(b.max()+2); b[b==-9999]=b.max()+1; solve your problem;b[b==b.max()+1]=-9999`